# List files in directory numbered, when number is pressed it displays contents of file (.txt files only)

Tags: java, arrays, console

I'm quite new to java and I'm doing a little project for myself. My code at the moment lists all the files in my 'blah' directory to the console. I want the files listed with a number on new lines and when you type in a number (with scanner?), it displays the contents of the file. I'm guessing I need an array or something?

Here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\blah");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }


}
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: You can't do that in a console application (press buttons) you will need a GUI for that or alternatively you can have the user select a file by typing a number.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I mean, sorry I'll edit to make it clearer haha

Comment: You can have an array with all the file names and print them with a simple local int counter variable (i.e. 1,2,3 etc) and use the scanner to get the input say 'userInput' and fetch the file name from the array as array[userInput].

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest that :

- you display your int i for the number :

  System.out.println(i + " - File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
- wait for the user to input something
- if it's a number and that `number < listOfFiles.length` and the selected position contains a file which ends with '.txt', you display the file

something like that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\blah");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println(i + " - File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(i + " - Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter a number : ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader buffer = null;
    try {
        String text = scanner.next();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(text);
        if (number < listOfFiles.length && listOfFiles[number].isFile() && listOfFiles[number].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(listOfFiles[number]);
            buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        if (buffer != null) {
            try {
                buffer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much :D